# React Native data in context is undefined on the first render

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I use `AppContext`, when I fetch data from server I want it to save in context but on the first render it doesn't save. If I make something to rerender state data appears in context.

Here is my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch('https://beautiful-places.ru/api/places')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((json) => myContext.updatePlaces(json))
    .then(() => console.log('jsonData', myContext.getPlaces()))
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
}, []);
```

My `getPlaces` and `updatePlaces` methods:

```
const [allPlaces, setAllPlaces] = useState();

const getPlaces = () => {
  return allPlaces;
};

const updatePlaces = (json) => {
  setAllPlaces(json);
};

const placesSettings = {
  getPlaces,
  updatePlaces,
};
```

Here is how I use `AppContext`:

```
<AppContext.Provider value={placesSettings}>
  <ThemeProvider>
    <LoadAssets {...{ assets }}>
      <SafeAreaProvider>
        <AppStack.Navigator headerMode="none">
          <AppStack.Screen
            name="Authentication"
            component={AuthenticationNavigator}
          />
          <AppStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeNavigator} />
        </AppStack.Navigator>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    </LoadAssets>
  </ThemeProvider>
</AppContext.Provider>;
```

Could you explain please why my `console.log('jsonData', ...)` returns `undefined`?

I don't understand because on previous `.then` I saved it.

Comment: can we see `updatePlaces` and `getPlaces` implementation?

Answer (score 1):

*Edit to note that the code below is **not copy-paste ready.** It is an example of how to attack the problem – you will need to implement it properly in your project.*

The 'problem' is that hooks are asynchronous – in this specific case, your `useEffect` further uses an asynchronous `fetch` too.

This means that the data that is returned by the `fetch` will only be available after the component has rendered, and because you're not updating state/context using a hook, the context won't update.

The way to do this requires a few changes.

1. In your `context` implementation, you should have a `setter` method that sets a state variable, and your `getter` should be that state variable.

`placesContext.js`

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";

export const placesContext = createContext({
  setPlaces: () => {},
  places: [],
});

const { Provider } = placesContext;

export const PlacesProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentPlaces, setCurrentPlaces] = useState(unit);

  const setPlaces = (places) => {
    setCurrentPlaces(places);
  };

  return (
    <Provider value={{ places: currentPlaces, setPlaces }}>{children}</Provider>
  );
};
```

2. Wrap your App with the created Provider

`App.js`

```
import { PlacesProvider } from "../path/to/placesContext.js";

const App = () => {
  // ...
  return (
    <PlacesProvider>
      // Other providers, and your app Navigator
    </PlacesProvider>
  );
}
```

3. Then, you should use those variables directly from context.

`MyComponent.js`

```
import { placesContext } from "../path/to/placesContext.js";

export const MyComponent = () => {
  const { currentPlaces, setPlaces } = useContext(placesContext);
  const [hasLoaded, setHasLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchPlacesData() {
      const placesData = await fetch('https://beautiful-places.ru/api/places');

      if (placesData) {
        setPlaces(placesData);
      } else {
        // error
      }

      setHasLoaded(true);
    }

    !hasLoaded && fetchPlacesData();
  }, [hasLoaded]);

  return (
    <div>{JSON.stringify(currentPlaces)}</div>
  )
};
```